# Hold the kernel from upgrading by "apt dist-upgrade"

Tags: package-management, kernel, lts, synaptics

Ubuntu supports specific kernels for longer time periods, according to [this Ubuntu wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

How can I prevent the LTS kernel  in Ubuntu 18.04 (such as 4.15)
 from being upgraded to another version by the command `apt get dist-upgrade`, while having the capability to install patches for the LTS kernel with `apt get upgrade`

l'm not a specialist  I just want to stay away from upgrading to another kernel.

Comment: Why would you have HWE enabled? if you want to hold kernel 4.15.   The HWE stack involves a lot more than kernel, but some of the rest of the enhancement are of little value without the kernel being upgraded too, so why not use 18.04 with HWE disabled (ie. remain on 4.15)?  Your question makes no sense to me, you want to enable a function (HWE) but disable the major part of it?

Comment: I want to stay away from upgrading to kernel 5 and at the same time receive patch for the LTS kernel (4.15). So I searched for this problem and I found out that Ubuntu support specific kernels longer time than other kernels by patching it . what should I do .

Comment: If you want to stay on 4.15; don't have HWE enabled.  All security patches made to later kernels are back-ported to the 4.15 kernel (for the life of 18.04) so for security purposes it's far better than being stranded on say 4.18 which is now EOL & thus doesn't receive back-ported patches any longer. I would not have enabled HWE (though it's enabled if you install with 18.04.2 or later media by default so if a recent install the media you used to install either had it enabled/disabled unless you change it)

Answer (score -2):

I think you can try:

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-image*
```

It will hold apt to upgrade "linux-image" related packages